# Is there a way to override the overscroll glow effect in listview on Gingerbread

Tags: android

Does anyone know if there is a way to override or replace the glow effect on listviews in Gingerbread. I've tried to set overscroll mode to OVER_SCROLL_NEVER. But then you will get a "very ugly" rubber band effect where you bounce back from the end of the list.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thx!

Comment: Hey Kevin,

Were you able to find the solution? I went through android's AbsListView.java file and the variables mEdgeGlowTop and mEdgeGlowBottom are private. So, there is no way to nullify their effect. However, when I use OVER_SCROLL_NEVER, I get the same bouncing effect.

Comment: No sorry didn't find the answer.

Comment: hey Kevin i have face same issue . have u got any solution?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I change the OverScroll color in Android 2.3.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See solution here: [How can I change the OverScroll color in Android 2.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1/6623169#6623169)

Answer (score -1):

[`setOverscrollFooter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and `setOverscrollHeader()` are presumably what you want. Have yet to use them myself...

Comment: Tried that already and it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? It should obviously do something... what sort of drawable are you giving it?

Comment: overscrollFooter and Header are displayed perhaps a pixel or so high on the odd occasion that the listview truly overscrolls (I think it's part of the optimisations on list scroll rendering) - it isn't the same thing as the overscroll functionality to show a glow at each end of the list view.