# How to change the color of listview "end of scroll" drag color?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a ListView that has a large number of items. If an attempt is made to scroll the ListView upwards when it already is at the top of the list, the following orangish gradient appears in the Listview. I need to change this to a grey. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: First of all check what is seted as background of list in xml. Is that a png file or xml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1/6623169#6623169