# Overlay image at the end of ListView

Tags: android, image, listview, overlay, android-3.0-honeycomb

I would like to remove or change color of image overlay at the end of ListView (Android Honeycomb). In the screenshot which I attached, I mean the blue image effect on the bottom of list. It is not android:cacheColorHint - it must be something else and I don't know what. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: the below thread suits your needs.Hope it helps.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1/6623169#6623169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this on property on your ListView:

```
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

The API level 9 introduced the function onOverScrolled() for ListViews.

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOverScrollMode(int)