# Changing the color of over scroll in scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a small problem with my scroll view. Whenever a scroll view has over scrolled, it shows a yellow gradient (in my device, it may vary for other devices) at edges of scroll view. It can be eliminated by setting attribute as below in android 2.3 and above.

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Now i want to change the default color to some other. How to achieve this.

Please help me regarding this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: btw, please know that the color is not always "orange". it is dependant on the device.

Comment: let it be any color, is there any idea to change that color ?

Comment: According to this [post][1], there's no way to do it naturally.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1

Answer (score 7):

You should use the following attributes on your `ListView` :

```
<ListView
      ...
      android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/header"
      android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/footer"/>
```

You could also set them programatically using [`setOverscrollFooter(Drawable d)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and [`setOverscrollHeader(Drawable d)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Comment: i am not asking about ListView, for Scroll View.

Comment: As u r Answer i have implement but still not got any image on overscroll in Listview

Comment: Did you manage to change the color? Or did you just remove it? If you managed to change it, what did you write as drawable? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102108/custom-overscroll-glow-edge-color-for-listview

Comment: Has anyone seen how to do this for a viewpager?

Answer (score 2):

This EdgeEffectOverride library works nicely for all scroll-type views: https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

E.g.

```
<uk.co.androidalliance.edgeeffectoverride.EdgeEffectScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ...
    app:edgeeffect_color="@color/red"
    />
```

And

```
EdgeEffectScrollView gridView = (EdgeEffectScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.myscroll);
gridView.setEdgeEffectColor(Color.RED);
```