# Custom overscroll glow/edge color for ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

I have a `ListView`, and a custom style that basically looks just like Holo, but with yellow accents instead of blue.

When I scroll to the bottom or top of the list, I get the un-fitting blue. I made custom drawables for `overscroll_glow.png` and `overscroll_edge.png`, but I don't know how to use them.

How can I get my `ListView` to use these drawables instead of the system ones?

Would the `OverScroller` class help?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a reflection-like solution to hack your way to changing this glow color:

```
int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
androidGlow.setColorFilter(brandColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

I encountered the same problem, and it seems like a good solution, at least until Google adds an API for changing the color (or branding the color): http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/

Comment: Multiply isn't good because it will mix your color witht the default blue. You should use SrcAtop. It will completelly replace the old color.

Comment: Where does one call this code as far as ScrollView is concerned?

Comment: Hey Menny thanks for the post I can't seem to get this to work I have context set like this `Context context = this;`

Comment: Here is a working code: https://gist.github.com/menny/7878762#file-brandgloweffect_full-java

Answer (score 5):

Just use this library. I've only had a problem with wrapping context on a popup menu in landscape on a device that doesn't have overscroll (HTC One X/Sense 4.5). Works like a charm!

https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

Answer (score 4):

tried this? [setOverscrollFooter(Drawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)?

**Update 1**:

Oops. Nevermind. You've probably already seen [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/ZLD5Blw4svw).

The glow behavior is wrapped in the [EdgeEffect class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html). You could disable the default edge effects by calling `setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER)` on your ListView and then rolling your own EdgeEffect class (the details of which are beyond me at this point).

**Update 2**:

Ouch. The calls on the EdgeEffect object created within AbsListView are buried deep within the scrolling logic. Could be tough. An easy fix would be a feature request to the Android team for a `setEdgeEffect(EdgeEffect)` method in AbsListView...

Comment: Tried the footer, wasn't what I needed.
So the only way for me to do it would be to create a custom `AbsListView` class? Too hacky for my liking :(

Comment: Well, I'm now convinced that it could be done by subclassing ListView and overriding a slew of methods (`onOverScrolled()` being the important one), but I'm not sure it's worth it. :(

Answer (score 3):

Here you are the solution:

```
public static void ChangeEdgeEffect(Context cxt, View list, int color){

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        EdgeEffect edgeEffectTop = new EdgeEffect(cxt);
        edgeEffectTop.setColor(color);
        EdgeEffect edgeEffectBottom = new EdgeEffect(cxt);
        edgeEffectBottom.setColor(color);

        try {
            Field f1 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowTop");
            f1.setAccessible(true);
            f1.set(list, edgeEffectTop);

            Field f2 = AbsListView.class.getDeclaredField("mEdgeGlowBottom");
            f2.setAccessible(true);
            f2.set(list, edgeEffectBottom);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }else{
        int glowDrawableId = cxt.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
        Drawable androidGlow = cxt.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
        assert androidGlow != null;
        androidGlow.setColorFilter(cxt.getResources().getColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please don't forget to change the overscroll edge line:

```
        final int edgeDrawableId = res.getIdentifier("overscroll_edge", "drawable", "android");
        final Drawable overscrollEdge = res.getDrawable(edgeDrawableId);
        overscrollEdge.setColorFilter(res.getColor(colorID), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this answer because this is one of the top results on the topic and the top answer is not correct anymore.
Well, it actually is for pre-lollipop versions but as expected, when you use java reflection you get bitten back, and that's what happened, if you use the code

```
int glowDrawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("overscroll_glow", "drawable", "android");
Drawable androidGlow = context.getResources().getDrawable(glowDrawableId);
androidGlow.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gm_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

this will crash in Lollipop + devices because that resource is not there anymore. So for android 5.+ you should use:

```
       <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/custom_color</item>
```

in your theme, overriden in a `values-v21/themes.xml` file if you are not targeting min 21 version