# How can we remove default Android Device colour

Tags: android, uiscrollview, background-color

I am going on with the scroll action in my Android Device if i scroll any thing in the device after it reaches the end point in top and bottom if even we scroll it shows some colours for different device eg:(samsung it shows blue light).

Here i attached a screenshot below:

[image]

How can we remove it or if no chance can we change the color

Usually we will use ScrollView,Listview etc to scroll the view should go on with XML or progrmatically.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >
```

TRIED

android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

android:scrollingCache="false"

list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);

android:fadingEdge="none"

listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

android:overScrollMode="never"

But no change can any one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: View = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.user_list);

        View .setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

Comment: <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        >

Comment: i got the solution below i posted the answer plz have a lot at it

Answer (score 0):

this effect is named `overscroll`

```
listView.setOverscrollFooter(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
listView.setOverscrollHeader(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

be awared that some devices ignores this params, [example here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZLD5Blw4svw)

Comment: Let me try and know for u

Comment: can we remove the default colour

Comment: because both the color the device default color and our assigned header footer color appears

Comment: use `android:overScrollMode="never"` or programmatically `setOverScrollMode (View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);` (API >= 9)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to completely disable the overflow in the ScrollView, but I have come across a library that you can use so as to change your overflow color.

LINK:https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride

Comment: let me try and know for u

Comment: Link only answers are not considered as good answers. Please consider posting some related codes and/or analysis to suuport the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which helped me to solve

[Custom overscroll glow/edge color for ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102108/custom-overscroll-glow-edge-color-for-listview)

for the user **Menny**

referred link:http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/

Hope this help's you