# How do I make the overscroll effect when scrolling at the bottom more obvious

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

This is my XML file, and I want to be able to make the bounce effect with blue shade more obvious when you're to scroll at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/explore_feed"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context="app.wanderast.activity.ExploreFeedActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/explore_feed_header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="60dp"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/screen_overlay"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@color/opaque"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/navbar"
        layout="@layout/activity_main_app" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzWX7.jpg) is what I'm talking about. My screen does show it, but it's very tiny and only happens once. I was hoping that by dragging the screen up even at the bottom will make that blue shade appear.

Comment: I do not know how to do this, but I can contribute to you by telling you that this "blue shading effect" is called **overscroll** in Android. Might help with further googling. Also found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102108/custom-overscroll-glow-edge-color-for-listview) that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question.

Comment: No worries, I posted just to help maybe guide you in the right direction. I'm not even sure you **can** customize this to be honest.