# How to change android theme color

Tags: android, android-theme

I need to change the color of blue glow that appears when you can't scroll anymore.

[image]

How can I change it app-wide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make your own overscroll drawable in the right color. [You can see how to set the drawables in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9062723/306257)

Answer (score 1):

The blue glow is created with the [EdgeEffect class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html). There is a third party library called [EdgeEffectOverride](https://github.com/AndroidAlliance/EdgeEffectOverride) that allows you to style the EdgeEffects of ListView's and ScrollView's without having to create any custom images.