# How is the name of foliage in this field ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

[image]

How is the name of foliage in this field?
I want to change the color, but do not know the name of the field to find in google, so I am here, I know it  stupid on my part ((ScrollView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually referred to as overscroll or edge effect. More info: [How can I change the OverScroll color in Android 2.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897909/how-can-i-change-the-overscroll-color-in-android-2-3-1)

Comment: Thanks you). name = overScrollMode

       android:overScrollMode="never". This working

I'll put you + after 5 minutes.

Comment: @frodopusto Consider accepting this answer, so to remove your question from the Unanswered Question Queue.